How to use external USB CAC Card reader and CAC with Chrome browser on Ubuntu 23.10
This is a howto of how I did it, So not really a question per se.
How to use a CAC reader, CAC card and Google Chrome browser on Ubuntu 23.10 Linux.
What worked for me.
Leave the CAC card reader disconnected.
As root install these packages and enable and start the pcscd daemon.
apt install opensc-pkcs11 libpcsclite1 libpcsclite-dev pcscd pcsc-tools sssd libpam-sss libnss3-tools gnutls-bin
systemctl enable pcscd
systemctl start pcscd
The next steps are to be done as a standard user not as root.
List the modules that are currentley available using this command:
modutil -list -dbdir $HOME/.pki/nssdb/
My system had the following:
Listing of PKCS #11 Modules

NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;library-description=NSS%20Internal%20Crypto%20Services;library-version=3.98
slots: 2 slots attached
status: loaded
slot: NSS Internal Cryptographic Services
token: NSS Generic Crypto Services
uri: pkcs11:token=NSS%20Generic%20Crypto%20Services;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203
slot: NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services
token: NSS Certificate DB
uri: pkcs11:token=NSS%20Certificate%20DB;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203


You need to add the CAC module for your CAC reader to function and the system to be able to read a CAC card.
To do this connect your CAC reader without the CAC card inserted (I had to do it this way) and run the following command to add the module:
modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -add "CAC Module" -libfile /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
Verify it was added correctly by running the list command again and you should see a second entry, "2.":
modutil -list -dbdir $HOME/.pki/nssdb/

CAC Module
library name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=OpenSC%20Project;library-description=OpenSC%20smartcard%20framework;library-version=0.23
slots: 1 slot attached
status: loaded
slot: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
token:
uri: pkcs11:


Remove the CAC reader from your system and run list again:
modutil -list -dbdir $HOME/.pki/nssdb/

CAC Module
library name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=OpenSC%20Project;library-description=OpenSC%20smartcard%20framework;library-version=0.23
slots: There are no slots attached to this module
status: loaded

Notice the slots: portion says “slots: There are no slots attached to this module”, that is normal.
IF YOU NEED TO REMOVE  THE CAC MODULE:
modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -delete "CAC Module"
You may need to restart the pcscd daemon again:
sudo systemctl restart pcscd
Now connect your CAC reader and in insert your CAC Card and run the following command to test. You should be presented with a password or PIN prompt, enter your PIN.
certutil -L -d .pki/nssdb/ -h "all"
Certificate Nickname                                         My CertName
SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
Enter Password or Pin for "YOUR.NAME.123456789":
YOUR.NAME.123456789:Certificate for PIV Authentication u,u,u
YOUR.NAME.123456789 :Certificate for Digital Signature u,u,u
YOUR.NAME.123456789 :Certificate for Key Management  u,u,u
YOUR.NAME.123456789 :Certificate for Card Authentication u,u,u
If all of this is working you should now be able to use Google Chrome and your CAC and PIN to auth login to your web site.

Posting stuff like this here is fine, but you should still follow a q & a format. Most of this should be posted as an answer.
